# jQuery password validation fails

Tags: jquery

Password and email validation, at first look everything it works fine but if you start playing with a password you will see what is wrong there.

So my password validation is pretty simple if its valid I add class to input `valid` which makes border green, if it's not valid, it adds a class `invalid` which makes border red.

This works the same for every input (`username`, `password`, `repassword`, `email`) as I mentioned before at first look everything works fine, but it's not  because password and repassword gets bugged and I don't really get why.

Here is my code :

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name*="password"]').keyup(function() {
      var password = $('input[name="password"]').val();
      var repassword = $('input[name="repassword"]').val();
      var isValid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/.test(password);
      var length = password.length;
      if (isValid && (length > 4) && (length < 16)) {
        if (password == repassword) {
          $('input[name="password"]').attr('class', 'valid');
          $('input[name="repassword"]').attr('class', 'valid');
        } else {
          $('input[name="repassword"]').attr('class', 'invalid');
        }
        if (password == "") {
          $('input[name="password"]').attr('class', 'invalid');
          $('input[name="repassword"]').attr('class', 'invalid');
        } else {
          $('input[name="password"]').attr('class', 'valid');
        }
      } else {
        $('input[name="password"]').attr('class', 'invalid');
        $('input[name="repassword"]').attr('class', 'invalid');
      }
    });
    $('#username').on('input', function() {
      $("#username").removeClass();
      var username = $(this).val();
      var isValid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/.test(username);
      var length = username.length;
      if (isValid && (length > 4) && (length < 16)) {
        $("#username").addClass("valid");
      } else {
        $("#username").addClass("invalid");
      }
    });
    $('#email').on('input', function() {
      $("#email").removeClass();
      var username = $(this).val();
      var isValid = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(username);
      if (isValid) {
        $("#email").addClass("valid");
      } else {
        $("#email").addClass("invalid");
      }
    });


    $("#regdetails input").on('input', function() {
      if ($("#regdetails input:not(#loginsubmitbutton2)").length === $("#regdetails input.valid").length) {
        $("#loginsubmitbutton2").show();
      } else {
        $("#loginsubmitbutton2").hide();
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
regdetails {
  width: 300px;
}
.valid {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0.5px rgba(0, 255, 0, 1);
}
.invalid {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0.5px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
#register2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  height: auto;
  ;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #1a171a;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
#loginsubmitbutton2 {
  background-color: #007abc;
  height: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #0a3a8e;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-shadow: #ffffff 0 1px 0;
  border: 1px solid #f7ad00;
  background: #f7ad00;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0;
}
#loginsubmitbutton2:hover {
  border: 1px solid #00519d;
  text-shadow: #2b2e28 0 1px 0;
  background: #00519d;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="register2">
  <p><b>Registration Step (3/3)</b>
  </p>
  <div id="regdetails">
    <b>Fill your details:</b>
    <BR>
    <br>
    <form action="#" method="post">
      Username:
      <br>
      <input id="username" type="text" name="username">
      <br>Password:
      <br>
      <input id="password" type="password" name="password">
      <br>Re-Password:
      <br>
      <input id="repassword" type="password" name="repassword">
      <br>Email:
      <br>
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input id="loginsubmitbutton2" type="submit" name="next" value="Next">
      <br>
      <br>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Just fill everything in correct form so every field will be valid and then try to play with password and repassword fields, just add one character on any of them and you will get what I mean this video will explain a little bit better : https://youtu.be/6uHxXu7eAv4

Comment: How to reproduce the problem? what inputs dont work for you?

Comment: as i said at first look everything is working fine , but if i fill all field correct and then just add a char to password field and u will see because if you add a char to password field is becomes invalid cuz password and repassword wont mach then , but button will be showing still , and if u mach them button will disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by changing this :

```
$("#regdetails input").on('input', function(){
        if($("#regdetails input:not(#loginsubmitbutton2)").length === $("#regdetails input.valid").length){
            $("#loginsubmitbutton2").show();
        }else{
            $("#loginsubmitbutton2").hide();
        }
    });
```

into this :

```
$("#regdetails input").on('input keyup', function(){
        if($("#regdetails input:not(#loginsubmitbutton2)").length === $("#regdetails input.valid").length){
            $("#loginsubmitbutton2").show();
        }else{
            $("#loginsubmitbutton2").hide();
        }
    });
```

i just change $("#regdetails input").on('input', function() to input keyup